# How to run a method from another cs file

Tags: c#

I need to run a method from another form but when I make an object it makes my main form pretty much useless because the data in the lists get reset. And I cant make it static either because I'm working with a listbox. Are there other ways to workaround these things or do I need to rewrite everything.

Comment: It sounds like you want to pass an existing instance as a parameter.

Comment: You could make a DLL / common library.

Comment: Please provide some code example so we could better understand your question

Comment: Ill try making a library because Im going to run in this problem multiple times any links on how to create one?

Comment: Provide a code snippet please of the method you want to use in the other class.

Comment: Already changed it so got it working thanks for the help though.

Comment: you can use Messenger.Default.Send from one codebehind(calling class) and register the message in other cs file where your method definition containes. and from there you can call that method and the data in list will not reset.